# Find Max Color & Count

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a matrix in the following format:

```
     [,1]     [,2]  [,3]    [,4]   [,5]   [,6]  [,7]    [,8]   [,9]  
[1,] "blue"   "red" "blue"  "blue" "blue" "red" "green" "blue" "blue"
[2,] "green"  "red" "blue"  "blue" "blue" "red" "green" "blue" "blue"
[3,] "yellow" "red" "blue"  "blue" "blue" "red" "green" "blue" "blue"
[4,] "red"    "red" "blue"  "blue" "blue" "red" "green" "blue" "blue"
[5,] "blue"   "red" "green" "blue" "blue" "red" "green" "blue" "blue"
[6,] "green"  "red" "green" "blue" "blue" "red" "green" "blue" "blue"
 ...
```

How do I quickly calculate the max color and count per row.

For instance, for row 1, it would be "blue, 6". I am doing this via an apply command that calls "table".

However, my matrix has 1.9 million rows so it takes too long. How can I vectorize this?

Comment: Can you show the code that you're currently using as comparison?

Comment: How long is "too long"? How quickly do you need this done? If you can't answer that then I don't think you can say how long "too long" is.

Comment: Although someone posted the solution which sped things up tremendously -- the code used to run in 40 seconds or so. The solution takes just about a second which is perfect :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many different possibilities do you have for each cell of the matrix? Is it just like in your example? If yes something like the following may be faster

```
dat <- structure(c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "blue", "green", 
    "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "green", "green", "red", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
    "red", "blue", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "green"), .Dim = c(7L, 
    9L))

values <- c("blue", "red", "green", "yellow")
counts <- vapply(values, function(value) rowSums(dat == value), 
    numeric(nrow(dat))) # Thanks to @RichardScriven for the improvement :)
counts 
#      blue red green yellow
# [1,]    6   2     1      0
# [2,]    5   2     2      0
# [3,]    5   2     1      1
# [4,]    5   3     1      0
# [5,]    5   2     2      0
# [6,]    4   2     3      0
# [7,]    4   4     1      0

max.value.col <- max.col(counts)
max.value <- colnames(counts)[max.value.col]
max.counts <- counts[cbind(1:nrow(counts), max.value.col)]
paste(max.value, max.counts, sep = ", ")
# [1] "blue, 6" "blue, 5" "blue, 5" "blue, 5" "blue, 5" "blue, 4"
```

If you want to get the names of all columns, if there is a tie, the following would work but may take a while (not sure about the performance of `apply` in this case)

```
max.value.all.cols <- counts == counts[cbind(1:nrow(counts), max.value.col)]
paste(
    apply(max.value.all.cols, 1, function(r) paste(paste(colnames(counts)[r],     
       collapse = ", "))), 
    max.counts, sep = ", ")
```

Comment: `vapply(values, function(value) rowSums(dat == value), numeric(nrow(dat)))` might even be faster than `sapply`

Comment: @konvas If there is a tie among maximum counts, `max.col` seems to select one of them arbitrarily. Is there `max.col` equivalent that locates all the max values?

Comment: @RichardScriven Good point! That should improve the speed quite a bit.

Comment: @Khashaa Have a look at `?max.col`. You can adjust the `ties.method` parameter but there are only three options available - random, first and last. What did you have in mind exactly?

Comment: Just that it would have been great if it had `ties.method=all`.

Comment: @Khashaa I see.. Not sure what's the most efficient way to do this. I've edited the post, but if this solution is too slow for you, we must come up with another way...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an actual data.table solution I think. Leverages data.table's fast `.N` for counting row frequencies

```
library(data.table)

flip <- data.table(t(mat))

tally <- lapply(names(flip), 
                function(x) {
                  setnames(flip[, .N, by=eval(x)][order(-N)][1,],
                           c('clr', 'N')) } )
do.call(rbind, tally)

#     clr N
# 1: blue 6
# 2: blue 5
# 3: blue 5
# 4: blue 5
# 5: blue 5
# 6: blue 4
```

I take the matrix and transpose it, then do counts by each column (i.e. by each row of the original matrix). The `setnames` bit is required so that we can conveniently collapse the results together, but if you are happy to get the results in list form it's not required.

I used the same data as others:

```
mat <-
matrix(c( "blue","red","blue","blue","blue","red","green","blue","blue",
          "green","red","blue","blue","blue","red","green","blue","blue",
          "yellow","red","blue","blue","blue","red","green","blue","blue",
          "red","red","blue","blue","blue","red","green","blue","blue",
          "blue","red","green","blue","blue","red","green","blue","blue",
          "green","red","green","blue","blue","red","green","blue","blue"), 
       ncol = 9, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: eh, but the t() operation is slow on large matrices. never mind